# Using const parameter for variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have two questions about the following variadic code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T Add(const T& arg_a)
{
    return arg_a;
}

template <typename T, typename... Pack>
T Add(const T& arg_a, const Pack&... arg_list)
{
    return arg_a + Add(arg_list...);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    auto itLocalSum = Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    std::cout << "Sum of Add: " << itLocalSum << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

1. Why is it used const reference for parameters?
2. When I use floating numbers with a combination of integers like `add(2.3, 43, 32.2)` it doesn't show correct value to me. how can I fix it?

Comment: Where did you get this code from?  This isn't a great example of generic programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Answer for question 1**

Because some types are expensive to copy, if you are simply doing a summation , which doesn't modify the underlying objects, pass by const reference eliminates the cost of copying the objects.

For example, if you pass by value a large `vector`, the whole `vector` would be copied to call the function, while passing a const reference is a lot more faster (**likely** implemented as a pointer copy).

---

**Answer for question 2**

Your problem is that when you calculate `43 + 32.2` the return value is `int`, discarding the decimal parts. This is because `T` in this context is deduced to be the type of literal `43`, which is `int`. Two solutions for your problem:

1. Use `auto` for your return value. (If you are on c++ 14)

```cpp
template <typename T>
T Add(const T& arg_a)
{
    return arg_a;
}

template <typename T, typename... Pack>
auto Add(const T& arg_a, const Pack&... arg_list)
{
    return arg_a + Add(arg_list...);
}
```

2. Or if you have c++ 17, simply use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)

```cpp
template <typename... Pack>
auto Add(const Pack&... arg_list)
{
    return (... + arg_list);
}
```

3. If you are on c++ 11, use [std::common_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)

```cpp
template <typename T>
T Add(const T& arg_a)
{
    return arg_a;
}

template <typename T, typename... Pack>
typename std::common_type<T, Pack...>::type Add(const T& arg_a, const Pack&... arg_list)
{
    return arg_a + Add(arg_list...);
}
```

When `std::common_type` doesn't work (for example, `Add('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`), you can still write your own sum type deducer in c++ 11:

```cpp
template <typename SumLeftT, typename ... Args>
struct sum_t_impl;

template <typename SumLeftT>
struct sum_t_impl<SumLeftT> {
    using type = SumLeftT;
};

template <typename SumLeftT, typename FirstT, typename ... Rest>
struct sum_t_impl<SumLeftT, FirstT, Rest...> {
    using type = typename sum_t_impl<decltype(std::declval<SumLeftT>() + std::declval<FirstT>()), Rest...>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
using sum_t = typename sum_t_impl<T, TArgs...>::type;
```

And replace the return value type `typename std::common_type<T, Pack...>` with `sum_t<T, Pack...>`.

This, for example, works for a pack with `char`s, where `char + char -> int`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto itLocalSum = Add('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    std::cout << typeid(itLocalSum).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum of Add: " << itLocalSum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Will output: `int` and `394`.

Comment: @max66 Thanks, added to the answer.

Comment: `std::common_type` is not necessary the best option, `char`+`char` -> `int`, whereas common_type is `char`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I added a sum type deducer.

Comment: Why when I delete the const keyword in function signature, compiler give me the error "cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'T &'". @KaenbyouRin

Comment: @cayotee You cannot bind lvalue references to [prvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue).

Answer (score 1):

1) It's just to receive parameters without making copy. `const` is just to make them "read-only", they can not be changed. Also, when you use a const reference, you can bind rvalue arguments to lvalue parameters, then you can also pass literals to your function, for instance.

2) There's an implicit conversion to int whenever the first parameter is an integer for each pair of the unpacking. If you change the `43` value to  `43.0`, it's going to work. Also, with C++17, you can discard the `Add` function and use a fold expression : `return (arg_a + ... + arg_list);`.

Possible better solution:

```
template <typename... Pack>
auto Add(const Pack&... arg_list) {
    return (arg_list + ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Why *wouldn't* you pass arguments by reference? For integers it doesn't matter, but I can just as well `Add(std::string{"QWER"}, std::string{"ASDF"}, std::string{"ZXCV"})` and copying those around can get quite costly.
2. You always return left-hand side type, no matter what. It means that if you have `Add(2, 3.5)`, the result must be `int` and it will be casted to such.

To avoid it, you can deduce returned type:

```
template <typename T, typename... Pack>
auto Add(const T& arg_a, const Pack&... arg_list)
{
    return arg_a + Add(arg_list...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the wrong sum... the problem is that

```
template <typename T, typename... Pack>
T Add(const T& arg_a, const Pack&... arg_list)
{
    return arg_a + Add(arg_list...);
}
```

return a value of the same type of the first argument (`T`).

So, if `T` is an integer, you loose the floating point parts in the following arguments.

In case

```
Add(2.3, 43, 32.2)
```

you obtain that, after the `43`, `32.2` become `32`.

To solve this problem... if you can use C++17, you can use template folding and simply write

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto Add (Ts const & ... as)
 { return (as + ...); }
```

If you can't use C++17 but you can use C++14, you can simulate template folding as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto Add (Ts const & ... as)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   typename std::common_type<Ts...>::type ret{};

   (void)unused { 0, ((void)(ret += as), 0)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Observe the use of `std::common_type<Ts...>::type` to get a variable of the the returned type.

If you can use only C++11 (so no `auto` without trailing return type), you have to explicit the return type

```
template <typename ... Ts>
typename std::common_type<Ts...>::type Add (Ts const & ... as)
 { 
   // same body as in C++14
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it used const reference for parameters?

When you intend to invoke it as:

```
auto itLocalSum = Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

the arguments have to be `const&` or just values. i.e.

```
template <typename T>
T Add(const T& arg_a)
{
    return arg_a;
}

template <typename T, typename... Pack>
T Add(const T& arg_a, const Pack&... arg_list)
{
    return arg_a + Add(arg_list...);
}
```

or

```
template <typename T>
T Add(T arg_a)
{
    return arg_a;
}

template <typename T, typename... Pack>
T Add(T arg_a, Pack... arg_list)
{
    return arg_a + Add(arg_list...);
}
```

For simple types, either is fine. `const&` will be more efficient if `T` is expensive to copy.

> When I use floating numbers with a combination of integers like add(2.3, 43, 32.2) it doesn't show correct value to me. how can I fix it?

You can use `43.0` instead of `43`.

When you use `Add(2.3, 43, 32.2)`, the recursive call `Add(43, 32.2)` returns an `int` and truncates the return value to `75`.